# How to force the type of an already declared variable in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a case where I know the type of a variable, but TypeScript doesn't. I can't use a type guard because I'm inside a switch-case, and because of a [known TypeScript bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2214) it can't be implemented.

This is the scenario:

```
function handleObject(obj: any) {
  let myObj: any;
  switch (typeof obj) {
    case 'number':
      myObj: number = obj;
      // use myObj as a number
    break;
    case 'string':
      myObj: string = obj;
      // use myObj as a string
    break;
    //etc...

  }
}
```

This is a simplified example, but there are tens of possible types. Obviously, I can't declare a different variable for each scenario only to assign a different type.

My idea was to declare a lot of variables like `myObjString`, `myObjNumber`, etc..., but it would sound like Hungarian notation, which I don't like at all.

In the above example, the error that I get is:

> 'number' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.(2693)

Because the variable was already declared.

If instead I use `myObj = obj as number` or `myObj = <number>obj` it compiles, but `myObj` remains `any`.

How could I get the variable typed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a map of type constructors to functions into your `handleObject` function, which applies the Open/Closed Principle because you don't need to modify your `handleObject` function whenever you want to support new object types; rather, you just apply the type and the handler function to the map and pass the map to the function.

First, let's define a type that represents a type constructor:

```
type Ctor<T = unknown> = { new(...args: any[]): T };
```

We can also define a type to represent the map:

```
type TypedMap<T> = Map<Ctor<T>, (value: T) => void>;
```

Now let's refactor the `handleObject` function to work with an extensible map:

```
function handleObject(obj: any, map: TypedMap<any>) {
    if (map.has(obj.constructor)) {
        const fn = map.get(obj.constructor)!;
        fn(obj);
    }
}
```

Let's add a test class:

```
class Foo { }
```

Let's create a map that we can pass to our function:

```
const map: TypedMap<any> = new Map();
map.set(Number, (value: number) => console.log("It's a Number"));
map.set(String, (value: string) => console.log("It's a String"));
map.set(Foo, (value: Foo) => console.log("It's a Foo"));
```

And finally, let's test that it works:

```
handleObject("hello", map); // It's a String
handleObject(123, map); // It's a Number
handleObject(new Foo(), map); // It's a Foo
```

Altogether now:

```
type Ctor<T = unknown> = { new(...args: any[]): T };
type TypedMap<T> = Map<T, (value: T) => void>;

function handleObject(obj: any, map: TypedMap<any>) {
    if (map.has(obj.constructor)) {
        const fn = map.get(obj.constructor)!;
        fn(obj);
    }
}

class Foo {
}

const map: TypedMap<any> = new Map();
map.set(Number, (value: number) => console.log("It's a Number"));
map.set(String, (value: string) => console.log("It's a String"));
map.set(Foo, (value: Foo) => console.log("It's a Foo"));

handleObject("hello", map);
handleObject(123, map);
handleObject(new Foo(), map);
```

It might be a bit rough around the edges, but it seems to work nicely.

Comment: This is nice. It would mean remove the big switch-case and use many different callbacks. I'd prefer to keep the switch-case, but I'm gonna consider this solution anyway since it looks a bit cleaner. Did you invent this pattern or you saw it anywhere?

Comment: I didn't invent this, it was shown to me a long time ago as an alternative to using switch statements. I tend to use this rather than `switch` especially where cases change over time as this respects OCP (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) _See also, SOLID principles_

Comment: Thank you, I've never seen this in TypeScript, I'm gonna deepen it. I wonder if there's a way to put this logic inside an observable, but maybe it deserves a different question on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

@MatthewLayton's answer is exemplary. I've anyway found a simpler way to force the type of an already declared variable. Using curly brackets around a `case` of a *switch-case* is enough to create a new block-scope:

```
function handleObject(obj: any) {
  switch (typeof obj) {
    case 'number': {
      const myObj: number = obj;
      // use myObj as a number
      break;
    }
    case 'string': {
      const myObj: string = obj;
      // use myObj as a string
      break;
      //etc...
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: This will only work for _primitive_ types (string, number, boolean, object). For example if `obj` was constructed from `Foo`, then `typeof obj` will be `object` rather than `Foo` so you won't be able to specify custom types in your switch statement. If you ONLY want to allow `obj` to be a string or a number, you could also specify `obj` as a union type thereof: `function handleObject(obj: string|number) { ... }`

Comment: Yes, this was just an example. In my actual code, the type is received as a string from the server. For this reason type guards would be good, but they don't work in this context